# CSS3 increase image on hover and display div

Tags: css

So, i have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBNmU/2/). I want to hover over an image, zoom on it, and display over it the imageover div with an 0.6 opacity. This fiddle is what i've done so far. Any ideas?

```
<div class="imageover">
    <a href="google.com">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>  
        <h2>Name</h2>
     </a>
</div>

<div class="featured-image">
    <img src="http://media.npr.org/images/picture-show-flickr-promo.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/rBNmU/4/)

Enter the imageover div inside the feature-image div

```
.featured-image:hover .imageover {
    display:block;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```